Virt-Manager Closes VM Automatically When Switching Desktops
OS: Linux - Fedora 41
Applications: KVM/QEMU under Virt-Manager
Whenever I'm running virt-manager and have a vm running and I switch to a different virtual desktop on my host os for awhile the vm running in virt-manager stops and closes. I have to re-run the vm again to have it activate. I'm not sure what's going on and why this keeps happening. Nothing in my power management settings seem to be contributing to the issue.
Any ideas?
It makes it difficult to do work on a vm if it automatically closes when I switch over to another virtual desktop.
All suggestions are appreciated. Thanks.

You're not alone, same problem here on NixOS unstable. Kernel is 6.11.5. Libvirt is version 10.9.0. KDE Plasma is version 6.2.3 (Frameworks 6.80, Qt 6.8.0). Using the Wayland session. AMD CPU + GPU, running mesa 24.0.7.
Whenever I have the VM open, and switch between virtual desktops, it randomly crashes in the background. When I only use one desktop, I can keep using it for hours without crashing. Sometimes, it doesn't just crash my VM, but my whole Laptop.
I don't even know how to debug this. Maybe I'll take a look at the previous dmesg or journald log after it crashes my system again.
Edit: Happened again and the journald + dmesg logs don't show anything useful. It looks like the log is cut-off and the error hasn't been written to disk.
Edit 2:
Looks like it was a bug in the kernel. This looks like our issue: https://www.phoronix.com/news/Linux-Clear-VMLOAD-VMSAVE-Zen4

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
